# How to install Valgrind on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, valgrind

I have tried with 
http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/dist.install.html

But after the make,I got

```
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/milenko/valgrind-3.11.0/mpi'
Making all in solaris
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/milenko/valgrind-3.11.0/solaris'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/milenko/valgrind-3.11.0/solaris'
Making all in docs
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/milenko/valgrind-3.11.0/docs'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/milenko/valgrind-3.11.0/docs'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/milenko/valgrind-3.11.0'
```

I am on x86.Then I tried

```
sudo apt-get install valgrind
```

but when I try to invoke it from command line

```
valgrind
valgrind: no program specified
valgrind: Use --help for more information.
```

Why?

Comment: It's installed - you're just not invoking it properly. Try `valgrind <executable-name>`.

Comment: @PaulR No, I have tried, valgrind birrp
valgrind: birrp: command not found

Comment: You may need the path to the executable - if it's in your current directory try `valgrind ./birrp`.

Comment: @PaulR Yes,it works now,thanks!

Comment: valgrind: ./birrp: No such file or directory

Comment: valgrind --version

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Paul R's comment may need to be put as answer.

I don't see any error in the `make` log.
Your output of calling `valgrind` actually shows it has been correctly installed.

See [here](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html#quick-start.intro) for the usage of `valgrind`. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/320632/why-do-i-need-to-type-before-executing-a-program-in-the-current-directory) for more details for your problem.